# Docker compose using parts of old images

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a compose file as follows:

```
version: "3"
services:

  oj-redis:
    image: redis:4.0-alpine
    container_name: oj-redis
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/redis:/data
  
  oj-postgres:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    container_name: oj-postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=onlinejudge
      - POSTGRES_USER=onlinejudge
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=onlinejudge

  judge-server:
    image: <image-name>
    container_name: judge-server
    restart: always
    read_only: true
    cap_drop:
      - SETPCAP
      - MKNOD
      - NET_BIND_SERVICE
      - SYS_CHROOT
      - SETFCAP
      - FSETID
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp
    volumes:
      - ./data/backend/test_case:/test_case:ro
      - ./data/judge_server/log:/log
      - ./data/judge_server/run:/judger
    environment:
      - SERVICE_URL=http://judge-server:8080
      - BACKEND_URL=http://oj-backend:8000/api/judge_server_heartbeat/
      - TOKEN=CHANGE_THIS
      # - judger_debug=1
  
  oj-backend:
    image: <image-name>
    container_name: oj-backend 
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - oj-redis
      - oj-postgres
      - judge-server
    volumes:
      - ./data/backend:/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=onlinejudge
      - POSTGRES_USER=onlinejudge
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=onlinejudge
      - JUDGE_SERVER_TOKEN=CHANGE_THIS
      - PROCTOR_URL=http://localhost:3000
      # - FORCE_HTTPS=1
      # - STATIC_CDN_HOST=cdn.oj.com
    ports:
      - "0.0.0.0:80:8000"
      - "0.0.0.0:443:1443"
```

Whenever I build a new image on docker hub and pull it with `docker-compose up -d` some parts of my `oj-backend` container get updated while others do not. When I access some API's they return data from the old build. The only solution I found was to `rm -rf` the volume directory `data` and run `docker-compose up` again.

I inspected the container and all the files are updated so I'm not sure how this is happening.

I need the data from the mounted directory in production so I can't delete it and restart from scratch.

Here is the dockerfile of `oj-backend`

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9

ENV OJ_ENV production

ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

HEALTHCHECK --interval=5s --retries=3 CMD python2 /app/deploy/health_check.py

RUN apk add --update --no-cache build-base nginx openssl curl unzip supervisor libffi-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev postgresql-dev freetype-dev && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/deploy/requirements.txt && \
    apk del build-base --purge

RUN curl -L  $(curl -s  https://api.github.com/repos/steviekong/OnlineJudgeFE/releases/tags/oj_2.7.0-beta.2 | grep /dist.zip | cut -d '"' -f 4) -o dist.zip && \
    unzip dist.zip && \
    rm dist.zip

ENTRYPOINT /app/deploy/entrypoint.sh
```

It is a django server.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is or isn't happening?  Which files aren't getting updated, and what should be causing them to change in the mounted host directory?  (If you're changing the `image:` name or tag, I'd generally expect Compose to completely delete and recreate the container.)

Comment: The django server itself seems to be sending data from an old image, for example I have an api that sends some configs to the frontend. I update this api with new values and build a new image. But after updating the image and running compose up I still get api values from an old build.
The build also curl's an express server from github and runs it in the same container. Any updates to this express server are seen in the new images.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a simpler problem?  You say it's one specific value in one specific  program; build an image with only the Django app (no Nginx, Express app, or supervisord), and show us the code that's not running correctly and what exact commands you're running to update the image.